# Source of quote attributed to Suidas

Tags: greek, passage-request, origin

> "Sophocles is wise, Euripides is wiser than Sophocles; but Socrates is the wisest of all men."

I've come across this quote in various places on the internet, including many scholarly books, and it is attributed to Suidas, but I'm having trouble finding the early source(s) of the quote. What is the origin of this quote?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[This page](http://www.stoa.org/sol-bin//search.pl?search_method=QUERY&login=&enlogin=&searchstr=sigma,820&field=adlerhw_gr&db=REAL) ascribes the quote to the scholia on Aristophanes *Clouds*.

The quote can be found [here in Greek](https://livingpoets.dur.ac.uk/w/The_Delphic_Oracle_420_P-W_(H3_R_(3)_Fontenrose)).

Comment: Thanks for tracking that down.  It quickly led me to a link with the Greek. *(I took the liberty of adding it to your prompt answer;)*